# Como colocar uma div embaixo da outra?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Senhores, estou tentando inserir uma div embaixo da outra, a mesma deve ficar conforme imagem em anexo, porém quando executo não está dando certo.

Segue um trecho do meu código, deve ser algum detalhe que devo estar deixando passar e não estou conseguindo identificar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.jumbo {
 background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
 background-size: cover;
}
.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px 160px ;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;  
}

.p1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: right;
}

.p2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  position: right;
}

.p3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: white;
  position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   GABRIEL P
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   10.000,00
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   55%
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   texto1
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   texto2
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   texto3
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
   <div class="p1">
   texto1
   </div>
   <div class="p2">
   texto2
   </div>
   <div class="p3">
   texto3
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta

```
.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 1rem;
```

Comment: Deu certo @anacvignola, aproveitando, sabe como eu posso utilizar o border-radius sem comprometer a div por inteira? e deixar conforme a imagem sugere? Pois tentei usar mais nessa minha estrutura atual ela quebra a linha em 3.

Comment: usar essas propriedades " css border-bottom-left-radius, border-bottom-right-radius, border-top-left-radius,   border-top-right-radius "